# Yii - create url for a controller action

Tags: yii, path, controller

I have a controller file "global", which contains function actionUpload. And I need to create an AJAX endpoint to use this action:

```
/protected/components/global.php

Yii::app()->createUrl("Path to actionUpload");
```

How could I specify the path to actionUpload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a link to a component. You can wrap your component in a controller action, but it is impossible to access the component direct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this global class extends CController otherwise this wouldn't be possible. So then you need to add a controllerMap to you configuration. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication/#controllerMap-detail

After that you can create url like Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('controller/upload'), if controller is the name of the controller registered in the above function.